Can I ask for programming codes related to quant finance here?
I require R code related to stock market and its analysis. I know how to program in R but I dont want to reinvent the wheel. I want to ask if users of this SE are using similar codes for their own project and if yes, whether they are willing to share those codes. Is it advisable that I ask for programming codes in this SE? If not what is the best way to attain my aim?

You can ask, but people will probably be reluctant to share codes if they feel you just don't want to make the effort. So if I were you I would make sure I can show in my question that I did look for solutions on Google etc...

Most of what you need is pre-packeged already into things like PerformanceAnalytics, Quantmod, and RMetrics
if you know how to loop, slice and dice you should be good. This is most of what i use anyway..
